# Разные результаты одного и того же значения

Tags: mysql

[image: id]

Ячейка id (int), а ячейка id_fb(varchar), в обеих ячейках должно было записаться одно и тоже, но записывается вот так, почему такая разница?

Структура:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как записывается?

Comment: insert into users (id, id_fb) values ("'.$id.'","'.$id.'");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По умолчанию в MySQL в int хранится 11 знаков, в varchar 255.

[Документация по численным типам в MySQL](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjTj_Kcq-PLAhUCkiwKHZbcD28QFggKMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.mysql.com%2Fdoc%2Fen%2Finteger-types.html&usg=AFQjCNG0R0Xx6aHajkgXEqFNGctagzAvCA&sig2=Gh7Jsy0Pdjq6_JW9Q6HZwg)

Comment: но я поставил 255 там и там

Comment: А уверены что проставилось? Покажите структуру таблицы

Comment: добавил скриншот

Comment: Посмотрите ссылку на документацию - там показаны максимальные значения для типов

Comment: Попробуйте хранить как numeric(255,0)